# Every function f: A $\rightarrow$ P(A) is not surjective

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

In this case the P(A) is the power set of A.

I want to prove this by contradiction, even though it's easier to say that the power set of A is a bigger infinity, I am not allowed to assume that.

So I want to proceed by contradiction.

This is a proof by contradiction, let us assume that every function is f: A $\rightarrow$ P(A) is surjective, we shall show that this leads to a contradiction.  Consider the set S {x $\in$ A : x $\notin$ f(x)}

I am not sure where to go from here any advice?

Comment: This is absolutely the right way to proceed. You are generalizing Cantor's diagonal argument. From here you ask about the $x$ that $f$ maps to $S$. Also, change "every" to "some" in your proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is surjective, there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=S$. Now, if $a\in S$, then $a\not\in f(a)=S$; and if $a\not\in S=f(a)$, then $a\in S$. The contradiction shows that no such $a$ can exist: so $S$ cannot be in the image of $f$, and $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost done!

Let $A$ be a set and $f\colon A\to{\cal P}(A)$ a function.
Consider $$S = \{x\in A : x\notin f(x)\} \in {\cal P}(A).$$
If $f$ were surjective, there would exist some $z\in A$ such that $f(z)=S$.
One might ask: does $z$ belong to $S$?
We have:
$$z \in S \iff z\notin f(z) \iff z\notin S$$
a contradiction.
Thus, $f$ can not be surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is surjective there is some $y$ such that $f(y) = S$. Then is $y \in S$?